# Can I have multiple console script names point to the same script in setup.py for a PyPI package?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

Is it possible or a good idea to have multiple console script names point to the same script? For example:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': ["the-popular-script = scripts.the_popular_script:main",
                        "thps = scripts.the_popular_script:main",
                        "the-other-script" = scripts.the_other_script:main"],
},
```

Then the `the-popular-script` and `thps` commands will both use `the_popular_script.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, without any problems.

The installer writes out those scripts at install time, so you'll simply get two executable files written out in the bin dir, `sysconfig.get_path("scripts")`, when installing the package. They will have same contents but different filenames.

Comment: Is there a better way to go about it then, so that you don't end up with 2 of the same script as executable files?

Comment: No better way.  And it's fine to have two of them if you want, the entry point script is only a shim - it will be not even 1 kilobyte.